# How can inlining in C actually be slowing down this program?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

In order to force a function to not be inlined that was consuming 46% of the runtime, I used `__attribute__((noinline))` on the it and compiled the code with `gcc -Wall -Winline -O2`(these plus `-g` are what is used by the Makefile - I also see roughly the same effect when using `-g` as well) using gcc 4.5.2. I found that the program with the non-inlined function is more than 20% faster than the original. Does anyone know why this might be?

Let me provide some more details. The program that this occurred in is the latest version of the compression utility [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/) for Linux. The key function ( generateMTFValues found in compress.c) in the program is the one that does the Move To Front transform. This function is only called by one function in the program.

Does anyone have any idea why the program runs faster in this case by forcing the compiler not to inline this function? The function only takes one parameter - a pointer to a struct that contains all of the block and compression info. Also, it only calls one other function which doesn't really consume any substantial processing time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can slow down the program, because the resulting code is larger and can lead to more misses of the CPU's instruction cache.

Comment: Is the code much larger even if the function being inlined is only called once?

Comment: called once at run or compile time?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant only inlined once. There is only one function that calls it. It is called a varying number of times (basically roughly once per megabyte being compressed) within that function.

Comment: How many *textual call sites* are there?  It could potentially be being inlined once for each of those.

Comment: @Zack, I'm not sure precisely what you mean by textual call sites, but I think that I know what you are getting at. This troublesome function that is being inlined, f1, is being called once for each block from with a function that is also being called once for each block, f2. f2 is not being inlined. Maybe this means that the code is being inlined into f2 for each call made to it?

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily.  To know how many times f1 could have been duplicated inline, we need to know not how many times f1 is called *at runtime*, but how many distinct calls to f1 *appear in the source code*.  That is what I was trying to get at by talking about "textual call sites".  When you say "called once for each block", you could mean that f2 (or f2's caller?) contains a loop which calls f1 many times but every time from the same place in the source code, or you could mean that f2 contains several different "blocks" of source code, each of which calls f1 once.  Which is it?

Comment: @Zack: It is the first of those options. There is only one place in the source code where a call is made to f1.

Comment: @Justin: Ok, then there *should* be only one copy of the function in the binary, whether or not it's inlined; so Peter's explanation is more plausible.

Comment: @Zack: That's what I suspected, but it's always to good to have other people confirm this.

Comment: I asked on the gcc mailing list and they seemed to confirm that it had to do with cache misses. I also used Oprofile and found that to be the case.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complete WAG (Wild Ass Guess) based on near-perfect ignorance.

Could it be that for the inline version the optimizer is really busy juggling which values are in which registers and when? If that's the case, the procedure call version may give it room to devote more registers to what is happening in the loop.

As I said, just a WAG.

Comment: I thought about something like this myself. It would be nice if someone who really knows compilers/optimization well would chime in.

Comment: <smiles> That ain't me, babe. Back in the 80's I was Mr. Debugger, but compiler people tend to be a bit more alien. :-)

Comment: I was going to answer this way as well, it can be as little as one line of code that pushes a function over the edge from being all register based to having to create a stack frame or having to evict a bunch of registers, greatly increasing the execution time.  Likewise it could be a cache line thing, go from one cache line to two or things like that.  Start by disassembling the code generated.

Comment: Looking at the function now, way to busy to be as simple as running out of registers, I assume this is x86?  And can you give more detail about the two build configurations, basically something repeatable that I can try myself, hopefully just gcc -c ... command lines.

Comment: okay, definitely non-trivial code.  a few thousand lines of instructions either way.  I dont think the stack frame is any different, is that function really called only once or once per bock?

Comment: if it is a cache line thing try adding some nops in assembler, 8, 10, 20, 40 whatever and re-test, try this near the beginning of either of the functions in question (the one you inlined or not and the one that calls it) this will move the code around relative to cache lines and you may see the performance change as well

Comment: actually, sorry dont put the nops in either function, create a new function before either, mark it as not inlined, and put the nops there.  the whole idea being to manipulate the binary to move the functions around in memory on different alignments.  the 40 something instructions difference between inlined and not could have caused other functions called very often to change their alignment and that is the root cause, may have nothing to do with the function in question.

Comment: @dwelch: this code is called once per block. I thought that since the call to the MTF function is only made in one function (which is in turn called for every block), that it would only be inlined once, but as I've stated I don't know much about the underworkings of these compiler optimizations. Yes, I am using a x86 system. I wonder if the effect doesn't show up for 64-bit systems. The build configurations are those in the Makefile for bzip2. I just took out the -g flag, though it wasn't necessary. The only difference between the fast and slow versions was the noinline line.

Comment: I am thinking Axel has th eright answer, I think it is a cache alignment thing.  Probably not exact but I did something that resembles what you were doing and it caused about 40 more instructions to be generated which will cause all the code that follows it in the binary to be at different addresses.  If any of that other code is a tight, often called loop, and it say changes from one to two cache lines or two to three, AND gets evicted by some other often called function you will see exactly what you are seeing.  with the inlining you can play with adding nops to move the binary around